# PHP check loop?

Tags: php, html, loops, refresh

I am trying to detected if a variable is the same as a string. If so the page will refresh. But if the variables aren't the same, then the page loads. But I need a way to keep checking after the page has been loaded if the refresh variable is the same.

Here is some code I have been testing but been **unsuccessful** with as the page just keeps refreshing.

```
$Refresh = file_get_contents('Refresh.txt');

do {
      header("Refresh:0");
} while ($Refresh == "True");


// HTML WEBPAGE CODE AFTER THIS POINT
```

If anyone can fix or redo my code that would be very much appreciated

Comment: is the content of `Refresh.txt` chanes ??

Comment: `while(file_get_contents('Refresh.txt') == 'True')`

Comment: @AbraCadaver PHP allow string in single quote? as you write `'True'`

Comment: It is always entering to the `do` block and that's why it is always refreshing. `do{}while()` will first enter to the `do` block and then check the condition. You should think about using `while() {}` instead of what you are using. Also, after serving the page, you won't be able to continue checking if it changed because the page is on the client already. You would need to perform an AJAX request to check it and refresh if needed.

Comment: @AsifMushtaq: yes, http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: I don't know what problem you're trying to solve is, but it seems like you're solving it incorrectly. If I was doing a peer-review of  your code, I would want to know what you're trying to do. PHP runs once. Your control code will execute once. There's no looping happening here.

Comment: `while(file_get_contents('Refresh.txt') == 'True'){header("Refresh:0"); } \\HTML CODE` Why doesn't this work @AbraCadaver

Comment: It will work just in case that the content of `Refresh.txt` changes !!!

Comment: @Halfstop How do I create a loop to check if two things are the same and if they are do the refresh command ??

Answer (score 0):

Try to think of it this way:

```
<?php
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = 10;
if ($number == $string){
  header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
 }
else
{goto:end;}

end:
?>
<script>
      Jquery Code Goes Here for Page Load
</script>
```

Comment: Create a div for where you want the page to load. Jquery code set the doucument ready function then   $("div").load("page,php");